# Create dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array while parsing a string separated with dots

```
$string = "foo.bar.baz";
$value = 5
```

to

```
$arr['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 5;
```

I parsed the keys with

```
$keys = explode(".",$string);
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Are there always 3 keys or any number ?

Comment: It has to work with any number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$keys = explode(".",$string);
$last = array_pop($keys);

$array = array();
$current = &$array;

foreach($keys as $key) {
    $current[$key] = array();
    $current = &$current[$key];
}

$current[$last] = $value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/BN9UtBLH)

You can easily make a function out if this, passing the string and the value as parameter and returning the array.

Comment: @dev: Because an array is copied when you assign it to a variable. If  you'd not use references, it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following solution:

```
function arrayByString($path, $value) {
  $keys   = array_reverse(explode(".",$path));

  foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
    $value = array($key => $value);
  }

  return $value;
}

$result = arrayByString("foo.bar.baz", 5);

/*
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["bar"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["baz"]=>
      int(5)
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow related to the question you can find an answer to, here:

[PHP One level deeper in array each loop made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854133/php-one-level-deeper-in-array-each-loop-made/7854395)

You would just have to change the code a little bit:

```
$a = explode('.', "foo.bar.baz");
$b = array();
$c =& $b;

foreach ($a as $k) {
    $c[$k] = array();
    $c     =& $c[$k];
}

$c = 5;

print_r($b);
```