# how to add key to php array as dynamic programming

Tags: php

I have an array look like this.
I would like to make current value (if not last in array) as a key and loop through array.

```
$_array = array(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => first
        [1] => title
        [2] => Harry Potter
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => first
        [1] => content
        [2] => title
        [3] => Chapter One
    )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => first
        [1] => content
        [2] => paragraph
        [3] => Hello...
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => second
        [1] => title
        [2] => The Lord of the Rings
    )
);
```

new array will look like this

```
array('first' => array(
        'title'=>'Harry Potter',
        'content' => array(
           'title' => 'Chapter One',
           'paragraph' => 'Hello...'
        ),
      'second' => array(
          'title' => 'The Lord of the Rings'
       )
);
```

this is easy to do this, but I want to make it dynamic.

```
$_new = ($array[0] => array($array[1] => $array[2] ...);
```

ps. sorry for my english.

Comment: how complicated will the data come in? Will the array *always* look like that first example?

Comment: @treyBake.. hi, it's a one dimensional array, but don't have same level for all.

Comment: I see that, but is it always going to look like that? if so, the most dynamic thing is the easy thing.

Comment: @treyBake..i'm quite not get it, could you show me how, so I can try it out, thanks anyways

Comment: will the data that you want to use, always come in the same format?

Comment: I have update my question..

Comment: I solved it by .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854133/php-one-level-deeper-in-array-each-loop-made?answertab=active#tab-top